# Clarification on For/Over Loop with Conditionals

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-of-loop

Reading through O'Reilly's JS Definitive Guide and came across this block of code:

```
let freq = {};
for (let item of "alabama") {
   if (freq[item]) {
     freq[item]++;
  } else {
     freq[item] = 1; 
 } 
}
```

Just want to go over some of the the syntax and implications:

1. Assigning an empty object to "freq" variable
2. Running the for/of loop over the given string
3. If statement checks if freq[item] returns true .. I get that part but what will trigger that truthy value?
4. And thus what how would a falsy value be triggered to produce a value of 1?

Thank in advance!

Comment: you may checkout https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp for 3

Comment: It's kind of like: `freq[item] = (freq[item] || 0) + 1`

Comment: thanks all for the input.. def cleared up the grey cloud

Answer (score 0):

First, keep in mind that when iterating over a string with `for..of`, the item declared for each loop (which you've named `item`) is each character of the string.

Since the object starts out empty, `freq[item]` will initially be `undefined`. For example, on the first iteration, `{}['a']` is `undefined`, which is falsey, so the `else` is entered:

```
freq['a'] = 1;
```

On subsequent iterations, when the character `a` is found, the `a` property *will* exist on the object, so the `if` is entered, incrementing that property value:

```
freq['a']++;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you find a letter not in the object it will return undefined

```
1) a
    freq['a'] will be undefined 
    therefore the code will set a 1 to it 
    freq['a'] = 1
2) l will go through the same steps as #1
3) a 
    freq['a'] will be 1 
    so it's truthy therfore we add 1 to it 
    freg['a'] ++; which will make it 2
```

Then you can follow same pattern to figure out the rest

Comment: got you! thanks Edward. its just that initial set up that had me a coders block.

Comment: @greenpepper38 sure thing, glad I could help

Comment: And I guess you're assigning ```freq``` to empty brackets as you are trying to create a list of the letters and how many times each letter appears correct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “freq to empty brackets”

Comment: you want to create an empty object (not a list) before you try to add any keys. Once you do this, then any reference to a new key will be undefined, which is why the if statements will know when you add 1, or initialize the count to 1. Once you do this, then you'll have all the counts in a nice usable manner referenced by unique keys

Answer (score 0):

in javascript the following are false
`"",false,0,undefined,null`..
in you case freq is an empty object

```
freq ={}
```

in first iteration of loop

```
item = 'a'
```

`freq[item]` will be undefined
if `freq[item]` will be `false`
so in else `freq[item] = 1` ie. `freq={a:1}`
same way for second iteration   `freq={a:1,l:1}`
for third iteration

```
item = 'a'
```

`freq[item]` will be `1`
if `freq[item]` will be true and increments `freq={a:2,l:1}`